# Getting the shortest 'K' distances in K-Nearest algorithm (Java)

Tags: java, nearest-neighbor, knn

So currently I have the following which finds me the shortest/nearest neighbor by taking the smallest distance value from my "distance" array which has the calculated distances. Then it does another search to track down it's index which then indicates to me which patient it belongs to.

However say I wanted to find the 3 nearest neighbors, how would I do that? Do I need to change my code entirely to accommodate for this?

Many thanks

```
    int min = 99;
    int d = 1;
    String diagnosis;
        //Finding smallest value from an array containing distance to new 'patient'
        for(d=1; d<= numberOFinstances; d++){
            if(distance[d] < min)
            min = distance[d];
        }

        for (int p = 1; p < numberOFinstances; p++) 
        {
         if (distance[p] == min){
            System.out.println("Nearest patient to new patient is Patient "+p+ " with a distance of: " + min);
            //Here I'm saying 6 because the diagnosis is in column 6 within the matrix
            diagnosis = data[p][6];
            System.out.println("The new patient's diagnosis is: " + diagnosis);
         }
        }
```

Comment: The first element of an array is element [0]. You should get used to using this.

Comment: How about sorting `distance` and using the first three elements?  Maybe some code to handle ties if for example the first four elements have the same distance.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, thank you for your input. I am starting from 1 because my CSV file has headers at row 0.

Comment: @AndrewS, yes I was thinking along the lines of sorting the distance. However I'm lost in terms of how I'd trace back the values. Because the index of the distance relates to my patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to accomplish would be to use Arrays.sort(int[])

```
Arrays.sort(distance);
int[] toReturn = new int[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  toReturn[i] = distance[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand this. If I do receive the 3 smallest distances, how do I then track them back to their original index position? Assumedly, the array is no longer in the same order after the sort. Many thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have two distinct but correlated arrays - one for patients and one for distance.  You'll need to create a class to hold the relationship between a distance and a patient.  Populate and sort that `PateintDistance` array on the distance attribute which will give you the related patient.

Comment: @AnthonyJ the best way would be for you to make a `class` that contains the distance and the index and implements `Comparable`